# How to get header information from mp3 in Android?

Tags: android, media-player

I am developing android music player .

I want to get the header information of downloaded song. Can you help me to get the header information of song ?

can i change mp3 file headers data ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090915/show-songs-from-sdcard)

and check other fields in MediaStore

Comment: Media store only gives information about songname,song artist,song album,album id etc.. but i want the mp3 bitrate , error protection etc information